# LeetCode: Leaf-similar trees C#

Tags: c#, performance, programming-challenge, tree

Please comment about performance

https://leetcode.com/problems/leaf-similar-trees/

> Consider all the leaves of a binary tree.  From left to right order,
>   the values of those leaves form a leaf value sequence.
>
> [image]
>
> For example, in the given tree above, the leaf value sequence is (6,
>   7, 4, 9, 8).
>
> Two binary trees are considered leaf-similar if their leaf value
>   sequence is the same.
>
> Return true if and only if the two given trees with head nodes root1
>   and root2 are leaf-similar.
>
> Note:
>
> Both of the given trees will have between 1 and 100 nodes.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GraphsQuestions;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace TreeQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/leaf-similar-trees/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class LeafSimilarTrees
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LeafSimilarTreesTest()
        {
            TreeNode root1 = new TreeNode(3);
            root1.left = new TreeNode(5);
            root1.left.left = new TreeNode(6);
            root1.left.right = new TreeNode(2);
            root1.left.right.left = new TreeNode(7);
            root1.left.right.right = new TreeNode(4);
            root1.right = new TreeNode(1);
            root1.right.left = new TreeNode(9);
            root1.right.right = new TreeNode(8);

            TreeNode root2 = new TreeNode(3);
            root2.left = new TreeNode(1);
            root2.left.left = new TreeNode(6);
            root2.left.right = new TreeNode(2);
            root2.left.right.left = new TreeNode(7);
            root2.left.right.right = new TreeNode(4);
            root2.right = new TreeNode(5);
            root2.right.left = new TreeNode(9);
            root2.right.right = new TreeNode(8);
            Assert.IsTrue(LeafSimilar(root1,root2));

        }

        public bool LeafSimilar(TreeNode root1, TreeNode root2)
        {
            List<int> tree1 = new List<int>();
            List<int> tree2 = new List<int>();
            DFS(root1, tree1);
            DFS(root2, tree2);
            if (tree1.Count != tree2.Count)
            {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < tree1.Count; i++)
            {
                if (tree1[i] != tree2[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void DFS(TreeNode root, List<int> list)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (root.left != null)
            {
                DFS(root.left, list);
            }
            if (root.right != null)
            {
                DFS(root.right, list);
            }
            if (root.left == null && root.right == null)
            {
                list.Add(root.val);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a problem with your approach: it always visits all nodes to build value lists, even when the trees aren't similar at all. By obtaining leaf-node values lazily, you'll prevent a lot of unnecessary traversal work if the trees are different.

This can be achieved by changing `DFS` to a generator method (using `yield`), and comparing the results with `SequenceEqual`, as janos already pointed out. You'll want to use an explicit stack instead of recursion though, to avoid incurring too much overhead.

However, for trees that are leaf-similar, the added overhead ends up making things slower. The fastest approach is probably a recursive method that does a depth-first traversal of both trees at the same time, bailing out as soon as it finds a leaf-node difference.

Comment: Witveot thanks for the code review, sounds very problematic to do that in a coding interview. anyway I like the yield idea thanks!

Comment: In an interview I would write a general-purpose `yield`-based traversal method that yields all nodes. Leaf nodes can then easily be selected with a `Where(IsLeafNode)` call. This results in reusable code that's both readable and still quite performant. I would mention more complex alternatives, and the trade-offs that come with them (expected performance gain versus additional complexity and maintanance, etc.), but only implement them when specifically asked to do so.

Answer (score 3):

In `LeafSimilar`, you could replace the manual comparison of the list elements with:

```
return tree1.SequenceEqual(tree2);
```

In `DFS`, I would call the parameter `node` instead of `root`,
to avoid confusion.

Comment: SequenceEqual I always forget using that one! thanks Janos